# Mapping CSV columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have the following code where I am trying to map columns from the input file to output.

I have written it using multiple loops. Is there a way to write this more efficiently?

#### input.csv:

```
  Name, Age, Gender, Nation
  Joe, 18, Male, British
```

#### output.csv:

```
First_name, Age_Years, Gender_F_M, Religion, Nationality
Joe, 18, Male, , British
```

#### code:

```
import csv

renamed_headers = {
    "First_name": "Name",
    "Age_Years":"Age",
    "Gender_F_M":"Gender",
    "Religion": None,
    "Nationality": "Nation",
}

with open("input.csv") as input_file, open(r"output.csv", "w", newline="") as output_file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(input_file, delimiter=",")
    writer = csv.writer(output_file, delimiter=",")

    # write headers
    header_line = []
    for header_name in renamed_headers.keys():
        header_line.append(header_name)
    writer.writerow(header_line)

    # write values
    for item in reader:
        row_to_write = []
        print(item)
        for value in renamed_headers.values():
            if value:
                row_to_write.append(item[value])
            else:
                row_to_write.append("")

        writer.writerow(row_to_write)
```

Comment: I suspect that all the parts involving "writerow" should be one level of indentation deeper (so that we are still in the "with" block).

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, applies to too many questions on this site to be useful. The site standard is for the title to simply state the task accomplished by the code. Please see [ask] for examples, and revise the title accordingly.

Comment: ah apologies the renamed header names were the wrong way round

Comment: Is "less code" your only concern? Why?

Comment: @Mast and if theres a more efficient way to write it - i feel as if I am looping too much in write row - what would be the best practice

Comment: I think your write headers and write values sections are both wrongly indented. Now the file gets closed before you're done with the writing.

Comment: I suggest you take a look at `pandas` if you ever need something more sophisticated than this. [Read](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) the `.csv`. Optionally [select](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html) some columns. [Rename](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) the columns. [Save](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) the data as a `.csv`.

Comment: I've fixed your indentation (the alternative was closing the question). Please double-check your indentation next time yourself, it's *very* important in Python as it will completely change how your program works if it's pasted wrong. Please double-check if what I've made of it is indeed how it looks like in your IDE as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have made a good decision to read the rows as dicts. You can simplify the
code further by taking fuller advantage of the `csv` library's ability to write
dicts as well.

It's a good habit to write data transformation programs like this with a
separation between data collection, data conversion, and data output -- at
least if feasible, given other important considerations. Such separation has
many benefits related to testing, debugging, and flexibility in the face of
evolving requirements. In addition, drawing clear boundaries tends to
result in code that is easier to read and understand quickly.

Another good habit for such programs is to avoid hardcoding files paths
in the script (other than as default values). It's often handy, for example,
to test and debug with small files. Paths to those alternative files can
come from command-line arguments.

If you want to be rigorous, you could extract a few more constants
out of the code.

An illustration:

```python
import csv
import sys

RENAMED_HEADERS = {
    'First_name': 'Name',
    'Age_Years':'Age',
    'Gender_F_M':'Gender',
    'Religion': None,
    'Nationality': 'Nation',
}

DELIMITER = ','

PATHS = ('input.csv', 'output.csv')

def main(args):
    input_path, output_path = args or PATHS
    rows = read_rows(input_path)
    converted = convert_rows(rows)
    write_rows(output_path, converted)

def read_rows(path):
    with open(path) as fh:
        reader = csv.DictReader(fh, delimiter=DELIMITER)
        return list(reader)

def convert_rows(rows):
    return [
        {
            new : r.get(old, '')
            for new, old in RENAMED_HEADERS.items()
        }
        for r in rows
    ]

def write_rows(path, rows):
    header = list(RENAMED_HEADERS)
    with open(path, 'w', newline='') as fh:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(fh, fieldnames=header, delimiter=DELIMITER)
        writer.writeheader()
        writer.writerows(rows)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```